# Add class to radio button if checked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, radio-button

I want to add the class 'selected' to both checkboxes and radio buttons if they are checked. I found below code online to make it work with the checkboxes.

What do I need to change to include the radio buttons also in the code?

```js
<script>
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var checkboxes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
    checkboxes.push(inputs[i]);
    if (inputs[i].checked) {
      checked.push(inputs[i]);
    }
  }
}

for (var j = 0; j < checkboxes.length; j++) {
    checkboxes[j].onclick = function() {
        if (this.checked == true) {
            this.className += " selected";
        } else {
            removeClassName(this, 'selected');
        }
    }
}

function removeClassName(e,t) {
    if (typeof e == "string") {
        e = xGetElementById(e);
    }
    var ec = ' ' + e.className.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'') + ' ';
    var nc = ec;
    if (ec.indexOf(' '+t+' ') != -1) {
        nc = ec.replace(' ' + t + ' ',' ');
    }
    e.className = nc.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    return true;
}
  </script>
```

Comment: Your snippet shows an error. *SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'*

Answer (score 2):

You don't need javascript.

There is a css selector for this, it's [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)

```
input[type="radio"]:checked {
    /* Use the css of selected class */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason some plugins in Wordpress removed that data. That's why I want to add an extra class to all the radio buttons and checkboxes. Below an example(this box is now checked):

```html
<input id="payment_method_mollie_wc_gateway_ideal" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="mollie_wc_gateway_ideal" data-order_button_text="">
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, I would assume you have to change `if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {` (around line 5) with `if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" || inputs[i].type == "radio" ) {`, then it should also include the radio-buttons.

Comment: I tried that also... Then nothing happens with the radiobuttons and I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: checked is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Here is the JSFiddle source https://jsfiddle.net/rj1405/Lnv70bsu/14/

Instead of adding the class name like

> this.className += " selected";

I am trying tho add through javascript method

> inputs[i].classList.add('selected');

please find the below code for your reference.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
   if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox" || inputs[i].type == "radio") {
   if (inputs[i].checked) {
     inputs[i].classList.add('selected');
     // console.log(inputs[i].classList);
           // console.log(inputs[i]);
   }
  }
}
```

```html
  

 <input type="radio" name="imgsel" value="" checked="checked" />
   <input type="radio" name="imgse2" value="" checked/>
   <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked>
```